# How to assign users in SageMaker Studio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have successfully created SageMaker Studio- Status in service. However, it asks me to asks to assign users to it and I don't have any listed. Are these users from my IAM (I have many) or my organization (I have a couple).

Where am I supposed to find these users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Did you setup SageMaker Studio to use AWS SSO or IAM for the authentication method?

From what I have gathered, the SageMaker Studio users, when setup using IAM for the authentication method are not actually users. They just provide partitions within Studio for different work environments. You can then control access to these partitions using IAM policies for your IAM users / roles for federated users.

Each Studio user has it's own URL to access that environment.

Here is the SageMaker developer guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-dg.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A14340%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C533.986%2Cnull%5D

Page 36 discusses on-boarding with IAM.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following blog post which describe how to onboard and isolate users for SageMaker Studio, either in case of IAM users as well as IAM federation. If you are using AWS SSO, then Studio is already integrated and users can be onboarded automatedly.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/configuring-amazon-sagemaker-studio-for-teams-and-groups-with-complete-resource-isolation/